# How to use a check box to change a formula

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, excel-formula

I'm trying to toggle what data is included in a formula. I want to include a range of cells in the formula if the box is checked. If the box is not checked I do not want to include the data in the formula. I was trying to use VBA to do this but I am not really sure where to start. Thanks for any help in advance!
[image: Screen Shot of layout]

Comment: you can use the linked cell http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/07/09/use-check-box-result-in-excel-formula/

Comment: You can do this without VBA.  Just add a linked cell and test it in an `=IF`.

Comment: What type of checkbox - forms or ActiveX ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the formula for the cell/range in the change event of checkbox. Replace the cell and formula values as per your logic in below code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

  If CheckBox1.Value Then
    'Checked
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=$B$4+$B$10"
  Else
    'Unchecked
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=$C$4+$C$10"
  End If

End Sub
```